# The graphic performance is very low for dell n5010

Tags: 15.10, performance

I am using dell n5010. I installed Ubuntu latest version 15.10. Do we have any graphics driver software to install?

Answer (score 0):

Identify the graphics hardware of your DELL Inspiron N5010 model, open a terminal and execute:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

When the output shows only the integrated intel graphics, suitable drivers are already installed.

When the output shows AMD graphics additionally you will have to use the open source radeon drivers, which are already installed as well. Unfortunately the proprietary AMD Catalyst drivers (fglrx) currently do not work in Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 4.2, see [Wily Werewolf release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes#Graphics_and_Display). You can check and follow the fixing process here : [The fglrx driver is not compatible with gcc 5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888).

In case you performed an upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 with AM drivers installed, remove them.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx  
sudo reboot
```

If you performed a fresh (clean) installation of Ubuntu 15.10 - this removal step is not necessary.

As far as I know DELL Inspiron N5010 ships either with only intel or with  dedicated AMD graphics.
Whenever there are special models on some markets that have an NVIDIA graphics card, you can install the proprietary NVIDIA graphics drivers as an alternative to open source nouveau drivers.