# Ubuntu 15.10 cannot download packages

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx

Recently, I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10, and tried to install wine. I had issues downloading packages.

I read somewhere that it probably didn't recognize my graphic card. I have a Dell inspiron n5010 and AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.2).

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

gives

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
```

I also read [The graphic performance is very low for dell n5010](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706145/the-graphic-performance-is-very-low-for-dell-n5010) but when I run

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

It says fglrx not installed.

How should I fix it?

Comment: This is a case of the XY Problem. You have asked a question as to how to fix your graphics card, but your actual question is how to install Wine. What is the error you get when you run `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`?

Comment: @Tim I wrote it here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/727418/ubuntu-15-10-problem-with-installing-wine/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `fglrx` installed, then you should install it. It's the proprietary driver for AMD graphics cards, so you'll have much better performance with it installed. Open the Additional Drivers app (search it) and select the `fglrx` option.

I'm not quite sure what this would have to do with Wine packages, but this is the answer to what you've currently asked.