# Ubuntu 15.10 - problem with installing wine

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I wanted to install wine to run photoshop and office, but came across these problems

when I run this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

and I get

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxjwf8eb2/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxjwf8eb2/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpxjwf8eb2/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F9CB8DB0: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK'
```

what are keys?!
and then I run this code

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then I get

```
Fetched 32.1 MB in 11min 24s (46.8 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E0F72778C4676186
```

again it said sth about keys, which I'm not familiar with.
also by runing this code:

```
sudo apt-get install -y wine 1.7
```

I get:

```
libapt-inst1.7 is already the newest version.
libapt-inst1.7 set to manually installed.
wine is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.7-amd64 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnutls26 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: wine-gecko2.34 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4 but it is not installable
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libpcap0.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: wine-gecko2.34:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I searched for unmet dependencies, but none of followings worked

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

is the problem from Garphic card? why I cannot download packages?!

Comment: You did not need to add any third party repository to begin with, wine is already in Ubuntu's official repository.

Answer (score 1):

To add that missing key, redownload the keys first:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E0F72778C4676186 
sudo apt-get update
```

Read about [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I run the commands and it got updated with no error, then tried to install wine again  by got these errors `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`